# Getting line by line in Apple Script from Address Books Note Field

Tags: applescript, automator

I have two lines in my address book's note field

```
Test 1
Test 2
```

I would like to get each line as a separate value or get the last line from the notes field.

I tried doing it this way:

```
tell application "Address Book"
 set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "space"
 get the note of person in group "Test Group"
end tell
```

but the result is

```
{"Test 1
Test 2"}
```

I'm looking for :

```
{"Test1","Test2"}
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things wrong with your code.  First, you never actually ask for the text items of the note :-)  You just get the raw string.  The second is that `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "space"` sets the text item delimiters to the literal string `space`.  Thus, for instance, running

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "space"
return text items of "THISspaceISspaceAspaceSTRING"
```

returns

```
{"THIS", "IS", "A", "STRING"}
```

Secondly, even if you had `" "` instead of `"space"`, this would split your string on spaces, and *not* newlines.  For instance, running

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
return text items of "This is a string
which is on two lines."
```

returns

```
{"This", "is", "a", "string
which", "is", "on", "two", "lines."}
```

As you can see, `"string\nwhich"` is a single list item.

To do what you want, you can just use `paragraphs of STRING`; for instance, running

```
return paragraphs of "This is a string
which is on two lines."
```

returns the desired

```
{"This is a string", "which is on two lines."}
```

Now, I'm not entirely clear on *exactly* what you want to do.  If you want to get this for a specific person, you can write

```
tell application "Address Book"
    set n to the note of the first person whose name is "Antal S-Z"
    return paragraphs of n
end tell
```

You have to split it into two statements because, I think, `paragraphs of ...` is a command, whereas everything on the first line is a property access.  (I usually discover these things via trial and error, to be honest.)

If, on the other hand, you want to get this list for every person in a group, it's slightly harder.  One big problem is that people without a note get `missing value` for their note, which isn't a string.  If you want to ignore these people, then the following loop will work

```
tell application "Address Book"
    set ns to {}
    repeat with p in ¬
        (every person in group "Test Group" whose note is not missing value)
        set ns to ns & {paragraphs of (note of p as string)}
    end repeat
    return ns
end tell
```

The `every person ...` bit does exactly what it says, getting the relevant people; we then extract their note's paragraphs (after reminding AppleScript that the `note of p` really is a string).  After this, `ns` will contain something like `{{"Test 1", "Test 2"}, {"Test 3", "Test 4"}}`.

Comment: Antal this is great. I tried paragraphs but understood what to do after reading your syntax